Почему в этом предложении не ставится запятая?
Глухонемая тишина налила дом и двор и весь мир.

Почему в этом предложении не ставится запятая?

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Цитата из книги "В круге первом" за авторством А. И. Солженицына.
В издании М. Г. Петровой, в котором "сохранены орфография и пунктуация автора", цитата выглядит следующим образом:

Глухонемая тишина налила дом, и двор, и весь мир.

Почему в этом предложении не ставится запятая?
Запятая ставится, причем дважды, поскольку тут однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимся союзом "и".

Можно еще так:
(1) Глухонемая тишина налила дом и двор / и весь мир.
Второе И (соединительный союз) соединяет пару "дом и двор" и "мир". Интонация ровная и не очень интересная.
(2) Глухонемая тишина налила дом и двор, и весь мир.
Аналогично, но И — присоединительный союз (пауза, запятая).
Этот вариант более выразительный. Кроме того,  нем обозначена семантическая близость двух однородных членов. В комментарии (см. чат) было предложено тире, но запятой, как я думаю, хватит.
